# Finding the distance in points between the top of the phone screen to the start of the image preview in the camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to build a custom camera overlay and need to know the height of the black toolbar just above the image preview when taking a photo. Does anyone know how I can go about finding this? I tired trial and error guessing it but I am worried the size is different for different iPhone models. Any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I am guessing it must be 44px with 20px status bar. So around 64px. I might be wrong. I would double check

Comment: hey thanks for your help, I actually ended up testing it by placing a red UIView covering the whole camera view and then tweaking the size. The top is 40pts in total. The bottom area is 101pts. Just wondering if these are the same size for the iPhone4, iPhone6 and 6+...